# Maximum near-lossless compression via dcm2dcm

Tags: dcm4che

I have uncompressed CT DICOM files and using `dcm2dcm` to compress lossless image from ~500KB to ~120KB:

> dcm2dcm --j2kr src.dcm dest.dcm

I wish to push the compression much futher, it must be lossy compression but like near-lossless using but dont know which is the best **encodingRate**. My goal is to compress ~500KB to <50KB:

> dcm2dcm --j2ki -Q [encodingRate] src.dcm dest.dcm

In `Oviyam` viewer, they made it down to 20KB-30KB JPEG and the image quality is quite well.

Comment: Is the `Oviyam` viewer using 8-bit lossy JPEG, and is the `dcm2dcm` using 12-bit lossy JPEG?  You can check the transfer syntax to know this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I found that if I convert from *.dcm to *.jpg (lossless), the image size reduce dramaticly. Maybe because meta data overhead.